# Can we [skip] this tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

[skip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/skip)

"Skipping" is an act of passing over part of a sequence of data or instructions.

Excerpt:

> Skipping is a construct that manipulates iteration (for, while, do-while).

Wiki:

> Skipping is a construct that manipulates iteration (for, while, do-while).
>
> For example in Java there are three skip constructs:
>
> 1. `break` which is skip the processing remaining loops.
> 2. `continue` which is skip only remaining steps in the current loop.
> 3. `go to` which skip all steps from current step to destination step.
>
> While Oracle Service Bus has two:
>
> 1. `Resume` will skip current stage and continue to process next stage.
> 2. `Reply` will skip remaining stages.

595 questions.

1. **Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?**
   No. The tag is misused and the contents rarely mean what the wiki describes. Skip an error, skip a test case, skip a line from text file, skip a song in a player, filter out values, etc.
2. **Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**
   It is too generic.
3. **Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?**
   Sometimes it does. [List of top voted questions.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/skip?tab=Votes)
4. **Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**
   No. `skip` is a very common English word with multiple meanings. *"If the tag commonly means different things to different people, it’s probably a meta-tag."*

This tag describes a very generic idea rather than a specific language construct. There are tags such as [continue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/continue), [break](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/break), [goto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/goto), which describe the contents of the question much better, but only few questions with [skip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/skip) are tagged with the other 3. This tag is quite often used, because OP used such word in his question. It adds noise and confusion.

Question count over time:
[image]

Comment: For point 3, I'd say it really isn't. The 7 top voted questions repeat the word "skip" in the title already, so the tag isn't adding anything to them. Looking at the 6 questions on that page (size 20) that don't have skip in the title, I don't see any that are using skip as the tag intends; they're all about the misused contexts.

Answer (score 8):

What a mess; it looks like [break-statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/break-statement) and [continue-statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/continue-statement) got merged into [skip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/skip); I can't say if it really happened or not but in any case it's clear the best way to do it is the other way around, and break this tag up into [break-statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/break-statement) and [continue-statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/continue-statement) and a few others and pick up and move the questions in [break](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/break) and [continue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/continue) into [break-statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/break-statement) and [continue-statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/continue-statement) while we're at it.

Once having done this, it becomes obvious the rest of the questions tagged with [skip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/skip) have no coherence and the tag can be burned away to nothing.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds good to me.

One of the other criteria used for determining whether a tag is worth is whether one can be an expert in that tag.

I don't think, given the many definitions supplied that being an expert in [skip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/skip) is possible.

Burn it with fire.

Comment: What about professional hopscotch players?

Comment: I'm cool with them using [tag:hopscotch] :)

Comment: The "can be an expert" criteria is hopelessly flawed. If anything, use a reasoning along the line of  "Would an expert use the tag to narrow down the type of questions they like to/are willing to/can answer". Only true experts can tell.

Comment: @rene *"Would an expert use the tag to narrow down the type of questions they like to/are willing to/can answer"* personally, when I say "can somebody be an expert in [tag]` that's pretty much what I mean. For somebody to be an "expert" in a tag, they'd probably need to actually *deal* with that concept on a regular basis. So, they need to be an expert in the concept itself IRL. Therefore main reason they'd be an expert in the *tag* is if they use it.

Comment: @VLAZ I have seen tags being removed because of this "expert" reasoning. It is not something anyone else can decide for them.

Comment: The closest expert I can think of would be something related to program flow control, but that's very different to the typical skip example of 'how do I print 1-100 skipping prime numbers', for example.