# Most askers [ignore] the wiki for this tag

Tags: support, retag-request, tag-disambiguation

The [ignore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ignore) tag has the following wiki:

> Many source control systems have an "ignore"-file mechanism that specifies files that should not be committed or tracked in version control.

The only guidance for when to use this tag is in this sentence:

> For VCS-agnostic questions, such as whether certain types of files should be checked into source control, use this tag.

So the tag is supposed to be used similarly to the [gitignore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gitignore) and [svnignore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/svnignore) tags, but for questions which aren't specific to [git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git), [svn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/svn) or another specific version control system. But the tag is mostly not used for this:

- There are 993 questions tagged [ignore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ignore).
- Of these, 158 are also tagged [git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git) plus another 9 that are tagged [gitignore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gitignore) but not [git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git).
- 101 are also tagged [svn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/svn), plus another 3 that are tagged [svnignore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/svnignore) but not [svn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/svn).
- Only 26 are also tagged [version-control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/version-control), and some of these are also tagged [git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git) or [svn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/svn).
- The remaining questions are almost all about "ignoring" something else in some other context; usually they are questions about how to get part of some data and ignore the rest. Here are some representative examples:

  - [Get only numeric part from column data SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68227472/12299000) - about "ignoring" non-numeric parts of strings.
  - [Laravel: method parameter bypass](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68019278/12299000) - about "ignoring" some parameters to a method.
  - [Reading coordinate file with ifstream while ignoring headers and writing to array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66870257/12299000) - about "ignoring" some parts of a file that is being read.

As another data point, the tag only has 6 watchers.

---

Should the [ignore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ignore) tag be burninated? Here's my opinion.

1. **Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?**

   No, the tag wiki does not accurately describe most of the questions to which the tag is applied, and the tag is used ambiguously for more than one meaning of the word "ignore".
2. **Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**

   The concept of ignoring some files in a version control system is on-topic, but the generic concept of taking part of some data and "ignoring" the rest is too broad to be on-topic.
3. **Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?**

   For most questions it doesn't, because "ignoring" part of some data is too basic and generally a question along these lines is about how to *get* the part of the data you do want, not how to *not* get the parts you don't want. Of the smaller number of questions which use the tag correctly, most are about git or svn, so they could be retagged [gitignore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gitignore) or [svnignore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/svnignore).
4. **Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**

   If the tag were used correctly (according to the tag wiki) then it might, but in reality the tag is not used to mean the same thing in all questions.

Comment: The second largest share of [ignore] questions (101) are also tagged w/ [[tag:svn]], which appears to be a source control alternative to git. The fact that 54 questions are tagged with both [ignore] *and* [gitignore] is kinda amusing lol. [More related tag stats from SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1398286/cross-tag-tag-usage-breakdown?TagName=ignore)

Comment: @zcoop98 Good point, and there is also a [tag:svnignore] tag which would work for those questions. I've edited to add this.

Comment: @zcoop98 I assume the latter (amusing indeed) fact is due to users treating tags like keywords and hashtags (I can't blame them too much, though, given how ridiculously low priority tags have from SE's standpoint), hence the "ignore" and "gitignore" (and many other "incremental" tags)...

Comment: Similar (vague) Use/Misuse with the [tag:skip] Tag also...

Comment: @chivracq There's already a discussion about burninating that one [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/387492/can-we-skip-this-tag).

Comment: Oh...!?, yep indeed..., hum, from 2 years ago and the (`skip`) Tag is still there, ah-ah...! Then that doesn't "sound" good for getting rid of the `ignore` Tag then, I would think... (Just had a (VLQ) Thread/Qt in the Tag I answer yesterday (mis)using it, that's why I mentioned it...)

Comment: Maybe `ignore-git` is better than `gitignore`, because if you type `ignore` it would offer to complete into `ignore-git`, but not `gitignore`?  The existence of `ignore-git` would also reduce people adding `ignore`.  Alternatively, rename to `ignore-source-control` and strip out the non-source-control ignore tagging.

Comment: @chivracq major tag cleanup/burnination is massively backlogged because not enough people are willing to go through the long slog of reviewing every question in a problematic/bad tag to fix/close them (followed by a mod making a final pass to delete the ones that are both off topic and of no intrinsic value).

Answer (score 10):

As usual, most of the problems with an ambiguous tag name (when the intended concept itself is specific enough) can be fixed if we can come up with a more specific name that isn't too long.

@Yakk suggests `[ignore-source-control]`.

Other possibilities include `[ignore-vcs]` (Starting with `ignore` may be better for auto-completion, otherwise `[vcs-ignore]` seems reasonable.)   <s>Or possibly `[ignore-file]`, although probably we don't want to rule out questions about command-line ignore options.</s> But that doesn't fully fix the ambiguity: it could be read as "ignoring files", not a file that lists ignores, and could apply to non-VC cases.

I'm assuming that "vc" is well known enough as meaning "version control".  Or at least that seeing "ignore-vc" pop up as a completion will be enough to let find it and check the mouseover to see if it's the tag they want.  Very long tag names like "ignore-source-control" aren't as nice, even with auto-complete; they clutter the question.

Update from comments: apparently people think we should use VCS, not just VC.  Semantically, `ignore-vc` would be to ignore a file from version control, which makes sense.  `ignore-vcs` is to get a VCS to ignore a file, which also makes sense, and apparently VC doesn't immediately make everyone think of version control.

Shortish names are better than long, as long as they're still self-explanatory and avoid ambiguity.  `[vcs-ignore]` would fit the bill.

Semantically, putting VCS first is better, and auto-complete does still work when the match is not at the start of the tag name.  With the bare `ignore` tag gone (renamed), `vcs-ignore` would show up early enough in the list of completions (which sorts by popularity I think) to work.

**So let's go with `[vcs-ignore]`**.

---

(@Yakk also suggested other ideas to make auto-complete work better for [gitignore], e.g. having an [ignore-git] tag.  Perhaps as a rename, although IMO a new tag as a synonym would be better.  This would reduce use of the generic [ignore] tag, but whether or not we do this, we should still rename the [ignore] tag.)

Comment: `[ignore-file]` could be interpreted as being about _ignoring files_ as much as _files specifying ignores_, which seems a _beneficial_ ambiguity to me, given the intended meaning.

Comment: @KevinReid: I thought the point of this tag was specifically to be about version-control, not cases like `foo  *.bar` but ignoring some of the files that would otherwise match a pattern, for example.  `[ignore-file]` opens the door too wide, not fully fixing the ambiguity we're trying to correct.  (Although it would be better than no change, I don't think it's the best option, or even really a good-enough option, so I edited to cross it out.)

Comment: is "vc" really used to mean "version control"? I've seen vcs, sure, for version control system, but not "vc".

Comment: @eis: IDK, "version-control-ignore" seemed reasonable, but maybe that's only in my head!  Quick poll: upvote this comment if you think "vc" = "version control" is a reasonable abbreviation, upvote the previous comment if you think think it's not (or just that "[vcs-ignore]" or "[ignore-vcs]" would be better than the "vc" equivalent).

Comment: I think `vcs-ignore` is the best option if the tag is to be renamed.

Comment: @kaya3: yup, agreed.  Updated my answer in light of yours and other comments.

Answer (score 3):

It seems there is support for renaming the tag to be more specific that it is only for questions about ignoring files from repositories in the context of version control systems, so something like `vcs-ignore` would prevent misuse.

In that case the tag should be removed from questions unrelated to version control. <s>There were about 700 such questions to start with, I will edit what I can.</s> **I have retagged the ~700 questions which used the tag inappropriately**; [this search query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ignore+-version-control+-git+-svn+-mercurial+-cvs+-accurev+-bazaar+-tfs+-gitignore+-hgignore+-svnignore+-tfignore+-github+-git-svn) looks for questions tagged [ignore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ignore) with no other tags related to version control; it should now have no results. (I also earned the gold "copy editor" badge in the process, hooray!) **The tag can now be renamed.**

While editing, I also discovered the [ignore-files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ignore-files) and [ignorelist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ignorelist) tags which had under 10 questions each, no watchers, and no tag wikis, so I edited those questions to use more suitable tags. These tags have most of the same problems as [ignore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ignore), and should probably be burninated rather than synonymised with `vcs-ignore` since they don't seem to be useful to anyone.

One more thing: there were a fair few questions asking about `INSERT IGNORE` in the context of SQL. Perhaps it would be a good idea to also introduce an `sql-insert-ignore` tag.

Answer (score -1):

> So the tag is supposed to be used similarly to the gitignore and svnignore tags, but for questions which aren't specific to git, svn or another specific version control system.

Don't you mean "but also"?

> The remaining questions are almost all about "ignoring" something else in some other context

Of course they are. That's because the tag name is super-vague. Suggest it be renamed [ignore-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ignore-file) or perhaps [source-control-ignore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/source-control-ignore). The former is more succinct but doesn't cover non-file-based ignore mechanisms, the latter is longer but a bit more accurate.

Now, @KevinReid suggests that people might think `ignore-file` is about ignoring files, but personally I think that would be pretty rare.

Comment: I didn't mean "but also"; the only guidance in the wiki about when to use the tag is this sentence: *"For VCS-agnostic questions, such as whether certain types of files should be checked into source control, use this tag."* Guess I should have included that in the OP, I'll edit. I don't have a strong opinion on whether the tag *should* be broadened to include VCS-specific questions, but my feeling is it would be unnecessary, and then the tag would effectively be about multiple different areas of expertise.

Comment: @kaya3: Well, I believe people would tend to ignore the guidance of "generalization-but-excluding-the-common-special case".