# Come [discover] this tag's problems

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

There are 51 questions with the tag [discover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/discover). 9 users watch it and it has no tag wiki.

**Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?**

Definitely not. The word "discover", alone, can't describe anything related with programming properly. It's totally ambiguous and is applied in many different and unrelated cases.

**Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**

If it's used with the intention of refer to the meaning of the "discover" word, no. If it's used to refer to tools, function names, among others, yes, but, at first, one could not determine it's concept.

**Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?**

As it is, no, especially because of its ambiguity. That tag doesn't give any hint about what should be "discovered".

**Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**

Also not. [discover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/discover) can mean: "to find out something that you did not know before", as from [Macmillan dictionary](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/discover), but it's also used in questions about the "discover" endpoint in HERE API, Kibana Discover and service discovery, for example. It's hard to imagine how someone could be an specialist in "discovering" things.

Comment: @BSdoukos I got the same impression as kaya3 when reading this post. It would be a good idea to edit an clarify it.

Comment: @klutt It looks like the misunderstanding which may be caused by that part of the post is greater than its utility. I've edited the post and removed it, also adding some sentences I think will be clearer and more useful.

Answer (score 25):

A few trends:

- [Kibana Discover](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/discover.html).  These questions are off-topic, because they're not about programming (it's a webapp).  Close them.
- Questions about discovery of devices and services on a network.  Retag to [service-discovery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/service-discovery).
- Bluetooth discovery/discoverable mode.  No tag currently exists for this.  Consider creating a [bluetooth-discovery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bluetooth-discovery) tag.
- [Oracle Discoverer BI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_Discoverer). No tag currently exists for this.  Create a new [oracle-discoverer-bi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracle-discoverer-bi) tag for this (a [search](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com%20oracle%20discoverer) suggests there are numerous questions about the topic).

Comment: " Retag to service-discovery" No, every service discovery has its own tag, be it bonjour, consul, or whatever. Each with their own quirks, objectives and tools. There's no need for a generic tag.

Comment: @Braiam The existence of more specific tags doesn't imply there shouldn't be a general tag for the same concept; see for example [tag:ignore] which [I raised on meta recently](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/410637/most-askers-ignore-the-wiki-for-this-tag); the current consensus seems to be that it should be renamed `vcs-ignore`, despite the existence of more specific tags [tag:gitignore], [tag:svnignore] and so on. There may be questions about service discovery that aren't about a more specific technology.

Comment: @kaya3 That's not what I'm saying. I'm saying that tags should be "specific, well-defined categories". Service discovery isn't a well defined category, nor specific. If we want to replace a bad tag, it should be with a good tag, not with another bad tag.

Comment: There's also [Discover for Delphi](https://sourceforge.net/projects/discoverd/) code coverage tool (for which the `delphi` and `code-coverage` tags are sufficient).

Comment: @kaya3 in the case of source control the reason for a generic tag of some sort is for "what files should I be ignoring" type questions.  eg `\bin\ ` and `\obj\ ` folders probably should be ignored regardless of if you're using svn, git, hg, or something else.

Comment: I drifted here from the more recent [tag:discovery] discussion - I think we can try to deprecate or find the more current name for Oracle BI Discoverer/Big Data Discovery ... are they the same product?