# I have made a terrible [discovery]: this tag

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

We have [discovery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/discovery), which is similar to the [discover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/discover) tag that [has already been removed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/410979/come-discover-this-tags-problems). I feel most of the reasons for [discover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/discover) being removed, also apply here.

**Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?**

Not really. There's [service-discovery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/service-discovery) and [bluetooth-discovery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bluetooth-discovery). There's seemingly WCF discovery, network discovery, etc. But this tag can't stand on its own.

**Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**

It is a general/broad concept.

**Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?**

No, it can't stand on its own.

**Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**

No.

There are 312 questions with the tag.  At least one of the questions only has the [discovery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/discovery) tag, making it all but undiscoverable.

Comment: Is there [tag:bluetooth-discovery]? I just suggested [tag:bluetooth-device-discovery] today...

Comment: I just noticed how we make puns with other tags too on this site and this [discovery] made my day

Comment: There's hundreds of different embedded system platforms named something-something-discovery. Like... it's hard to find an evaluation board _not_ containing the word "discovery" in the name.

Comment: Mandatory burnination pun: "I like [disco very] much: burn, baby burn!"

Comment: @Lundin After reading that I was so hoping there is a disco tag to burn. [It exists...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/disco). Unfortunately no disco inferno. Dangit.

Comment: "it can't stand on its own" has never been an issue. Lots of tags don't stand on their own, still they add context that is useful when searching for questions. There's a reason we can add 5 tags to a question, and not just one.

Comment: Upvoted for the outstanding clickbaiting title (which I totally fell for)

Answer (score 36):

I checked this tag. I can't tell good questions from bad questions; however beyond a doubt this tag needs a full disambiguate and burn, creating as many new tags as needed.

Xyz-discovery questions appear to be almost all on-topic. Only on the seventh of seven pages did I find negative voted questions. The tag is useless and needs to go away.

So far I've discovered:

- [google-api-discovery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-api-discovery)
- [computer-discovery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/computer-discovery) (or peer-discovery?)
- [service-discovery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/service-discovery)
- [bluetooth-discovery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bluetooth-discovery)
- [network-discovery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/network-discovery)
- [netdevice-discovery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/netdevice-discovery) (related to computer-discovery but will be almost completely disjoint--the only overlap seems to be the question asking how to discover all nodes on a LAN)
- [fingerprinting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fingerprinting)
- [snmp-discovery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/snmp-discovery) (possible too few questions)
- [wcf-reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wcf-reflection) (or is it wcf-discovery -- need an expert to tell me which)

There are a handful of questions for which the tag goes away and gets replaced with nothing.

Comment: While I agree with most of this, what the heck is [tag:api-discovery] supposed to be?  That one also seems like it ought to go away. [Late edit: For future reference, the [api-discovery] tag currently has three questions: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36289389/what-is-google-api-discovery), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53620161/firebase-projects-api-getconfig), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74955683/are-there-any-tools-or-methods-for-automatic-search-discovery-of-publicly-avai).]

Comment: google api discovery service?

Comment: perhaps it should be renamed to google-api-discovery

Comment: @RyanM: Yup turned out to be google-api-discovery ; I had to open the origin questions I generated it from to find out.

Comment: @RyanM the only question in there needs closed/deleted

Comment: @DanielA.White: Not sure what you mean. A tag api-discovery exists with the only positive voted question being a google api discovery question; but there's at least two more google api discovery questions in the first 50 questions tagged discveroy.

Comment: @Joshua it was the api-discovery tag now gone

Comment: I went ahead and renamed [api-discovery] to [tag:google-api-discovery]. It's almost no effort to change for a tag that small so if it needs to be changed again that's no problem either.